# SQL statement to update three columns from another column

Tags: sql-server

My table's structure is as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ontledings](
[ont_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[plaasno] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[plaasnaam] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[blokno] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[plaasblok] [varchar](50) NULL,
[area] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[analisedatum] [date] NOT NULL,
[name3] [varchar](50) NULL,
[kultivar] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[wingklas] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[kultklas] [varchar](50) NULL,
[suiker] [real] NOT NULL,
[pH] [real] NOT NULL,
[suur] [real] NOT NULL,
[last] [date] NULL,
[secondlast] [date] NULL,
[thirdlast] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Ontledings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ont_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Before the update the table looks as follows (only relevant columns included):
[image: Before update]

For each row I then need to update the last three columns with the third,second and last date for that row based from the analisedatum column (only for the current year). This needs to be done for all rows where plaasblok are the same.

The resultant table should look like this:
[image: After update]

Comment: Update the three columns with which dates? And as to a common value, what is the common value in the original table? You need to show your data structure or DDL.

Comment: First write a query that returns what you want. Does this return part of what you want: `SELECT Plaasblok, MIN(analiseddatum) GROUP BY Plaasblok. Please specify the version of SQL Server because it looks like widowing functions will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Editing,

First of all, your structure is not a good one because you'll have different rows with same value in some columns, and it's not good.

A better structure for this is to have a different table just to handle the 3 oldest dates of each *plaasblok*. For this you can remove the columns *last*, *secondlast* and *thirdlast* from *Ontledings* table and create another table with these columns. And then create a process to *SELECT* the 3 oldest dates in *Ontledings* table for each *plaasblok* and *INSERT* them in the new table. With this you'll avoid to have a big table with rows with same values in some columns.

The new table will look like:

```
plaasblok | last    | secondlast | thirdlast
03706A1   | 18/3/15 | 17/3/15    | 13/3/315
03706A2   | 17/2/15 | 16/2/15    | 10/2/315
03706A3   | 18/3/15 | 17/3/15    | 13/3/315
(...)
```

And the process can do this *SELECT* below to get the result you want:

```
SELECT
   A.plaasblok,
   MAX(A.analisedatum) as last,
   MAX(B.analisedatum) as secondlast,
   MAX(C.analisedatum) as thirdlast
FROM Ontledings A
JOIN Ontledings B ON B.plaasblok = A.plaasblok AND B.analisedatum < A.analisedatum
JOIN Ontledings C ON C.plaasblok = B.plaasblok AND C.analisedatum < B.analisedatum
GROUP BY A.plaasblok
ORDER BY A.plaasblok ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you Thiago. I hope my improved question is more clear. The dates are not at 1 day intervals.

Comment: Hi Gideon, looking your structure I tell you that it's not a good one, because you'll have different rows with same value in some columns, and it's not good. A better structure for this is to have a different table just to handle the 3 oldest dates of each _plaasblok_. So you can remove the columns _last_, _secondlast_ and _thirdlast_ from _Ontledings_ table and insert it in another one, and create a process to get the oldest 3 dates in _Ontledings_ table and insert them in that new table, instead of update and create multiple rows with same values.

Answer (score 0):

This involves a bit of self-joining inside a subquery to account for the multiple dates to be found:

```
UPDATE O
SET O.last = Z.last
,   O.secondlast = Z.secondlast
,   O.thirdlast = Z.thirdlast
FROM Ontledings O
JOIN (
    SELECT X.plaasblok, MAX(X.analisedatum) AS last, MAX(P.analisedatum) AS secondlast, MAX(Q.analisedatum) AS thirdlast
    FROM Ontledings X
    JOIN Ontledings P ON P.plaasblok = X.plaasblok AND P.analisedatum < X.analisedatum
    JOIN Ontledings Q ON Q.plaasblok = P.plaasblok AND Q.analisedatum < P.analisedatum
    GROUP BY X.plaasblok
) AS Z
ON O.plaasblok = Z.plaasblok
```

Note you can check the values using a slightly less complex SELECT - note how the MAX date for each join cascades to ensure validity of the next-most-recent date:

```
SELECT O.plaasblok, MAX(O.analisedatum) AS last, MAX(P.analisedatum) AS secondlast, MAX(Q.analisedatum) AS thirdlast
FROM Ontledings O
JOIN Ontledings P ON P.plaasblok = O.plaasblok AND P.analisedatum < O.analisedatum
JOIN Ontledings Q ON Q.plaasblok = P.plaasblok AND Q.analisedatum < P.analisedatum
GROUP BY O.plaasblok
ORDER BY O.plaasblok
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with using window function `row_number()`. First you are numbering rows in `plaasblok` groups by descending dates. Then you need 3 joins and update:

```
;with cte as(select *, row_number() over(partition by plaasblok order by analisedatum desc) rn 
             from Ontledings)

update t set [last] = c1.analisedatum,
             [secondlast] = c2.analisedatum,
             [thirdlast] = c3.analisedatum
from Ontledings t
left join cte c1 on t.plaasblok = c1.plaasblok and c1.rn = 1
left join cte c2 on t.plaasblok = c2.plaasblok and c2.rn = 2
left join cte c3 on t.plaasblok = c3.plaasblok and c3.rn = 3
```